# Limitations of simple type theory proof assistants for undergraduate-level mathematics?

Tags: type-theory

I'm interested in understanding the practical power and limitations of simple type theory, particularly as compared with dependent type theory, in supporting formalized proofs of theorems liable to appear in an undergraduate mathematics curriculum (not including theorems specific to set theory or specific varieties of set theory), using a proof assistant.

HOL4, HOL Light, and Isabelle/HOL seem to be considered as classic examples of implementations of simple type theory. If possible please also consider proof assistant systems hypothetical or realized, in which the base types are just booleans and individuals, and the natural, real, or complex numbers and such are defined as predicates.  (This is presented for N in Peter B. Andrews "Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory", supported by an axiom of infinity.)

For example, supposing the hypothetical curriculum includes some category theory, and portions of category theory can be handled reasonably with DTT but not STT, at what point do difficulties significantly impair the usefulness of STT?

Comment: My understanding is that there are two difficulties. First, to say something like “forall categories C and all objects x in C” it isn’t as straight-forward as DTT since the set of objects in C isn’t a type in STT (as it depends on C). This is also an issue with say topology or algebra and I think there are fairly standard ways around it. The second issue is constructing something like the category of sets. STT doesn’t have universes so there is no category that big. This is also an issue in ZFC. Again there are ways around this. It is likely subjective as whether either is a big inconvenience.

Comment: Kevin Buzzard has a good [twitter thread](https://x.com/XenaProject/status/1380935053409198080) (you must be logged in to view the thread) of the universe issue, and he highlights [an Isabelle/HOL paper](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Grothendieck_Schemes.html) which overcomes these issues.